# React-select: selected option doesn't stick

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-select

I'm a newbie to React and need some help to look this over to see what am I doing wrong :-(

I have a component, called Bucket, each bucket can have multiple challenges which is separated component, it looks like this,
[image]

The much-simplified version of code is this:

```
class CLL_Bucket extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {};
      this.state = {
         …
         bucketChallengesIdx: 0,       // to track the index of challegnes  
         bucketChallenges: this.props.bucket.bucketChallenges || [],
         …
      };

      …
      this.onBucketChallengeIDChanged = this.onBucketChallengeIDChanged.bind(this);
      …
   }

render() {
   const bucketIdx = this.props.idx;

   return (
      <div style={styles.container}>
         <div key={bucketIdx} className="row" style={styles.bucketStyle}>
            <div className="col-md-2">
               …
            </div>
            <div key={bucketIdx} className="col-md-4">
               <div>
                  …
               </div>
               <CLL_BucketChallengeDetail
                  challenges={this.props.challenges}
                  bucketChallengesIdx={this.state.bucketChallengesIdx}
                  bucketChallenges={this.state.bucketChallenges}
                  onBucketChallengeChanged={(challengeIdx, key, value) => this.onBucketChallengeChanged(challengeIdx, key,  value)}
/>
            </div>
            …
         </div>
      </div>
   );
}

class CLL_BucketChallengeDetail extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         bucketChallenges: this.props.bucketChallenges,
         bucketChallengeID: ""
      };

      this.onBucketChallengeIDChanged = this.onBucketChallengeIDChanged.bind(this);
      …
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div className="col-md-4">
            <div>
               …
            </div>
            <table className="table table-bordered table-striped show">
               <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>Challenge ID</th>
                  <th>Weight</th>
                  <th>Weight % Ratio</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
               </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
               {this.props.bucketChallenges.map(this.renderChallengeDetail.bind(this))}
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      );
   }

   renderChallengeDetail(currentChallenge, index){

      const challengeIDOptions = this.props.challenges.map(data => {
         return {value: data.ID, label: data.ID}
      });
…

      return (
         <tr key={index}>
            <td className="col-xs-3 input-group-sm">
               <Select
                  options={challengeIDOptions}
                  defaultValue={challengeIDOptions[0]}
                  onChange={(option)=>this.onBucketChallengeIDChanged(index, option)}
                  isSearchable={true}
               />
            </td>
            …
         </tr>
      );
   }

   onBucketChallengeIDChanged(challengeIdx, option){

      var newChallengeList = this.state.bucketChallenges.map((item, j) => {
         if (j === challengeIdx) {
            // found the specific challenge in the list that needs to be updated
            item.ID = option.value;
         }
         return item;
      });

      this.setState({bucketChallenges:newChallengeList, bucketChallengeID:option.value},
         () => {console.log("HERE: "+ this.state.bucketChallengeID); this.props.onBucketChallengeChanged(challengeIdx, 'ID', option.value);});
   }
}

export default CLL_BucketChallengeDetail;
```

The problem I’m having is, after I change the challenge ID, it does display in the selection field, and I can see from the React developer tool that the value has been changed, even the setState is setting the right value into this.state.bucketChallengeID. However, after I switch to a different tab of my app and come back, the changed selection field is reverted back to the previous one. What am I doing wrong??? Appreciate the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're always setting the default value to `defaultValue={challengeIDOptions[0]}`. So when your component loads it will reset to this default value. If these components are mounting every time you switch tabs you need to persist your state using context or another state management tool.

Comment: I'm trying not to use any state management tool so that I could learn more how React itself manages states. There were apps made before Redux or other state management tool exist.

Comment: @didi Totally understand but what I'm saying is that if your component remounts every time you come back to this tab you will need to persist state. That's how React works. Every time the component remounts the local state is reset and your select is set to the default value you have defined. You don't need to use Redux, you can use the React Context API which is exactly what this is for.

Comment: I see, sorry didn't read your answer carefully enough ... I'm not familiar with React Context API but i will check it out ... thank you for the lead!